# Reading authorization bearer token using dotnetopenauth oauth2

Tags: c#, http-headers, authorization, dotnetopenauth

I want to read the access token from the http request when the validate end point is called.

I was hoping that is as easy as calling

`ResourceServer.GetAccessToken()` which returns AccessToken object that contains properties of the token.

I could easily read from

`var accessToken = httpRequestBase.Headers["Authorization"];`

But is this recommended method? or how could I read the header in a safe way?